# How to get correct Type of a Class using Kotlin,MongoDB and Jsonschema "oneof"

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, jsonschema

We are using an message queue to get some events. These events are described as an json schema like this.

```
{
  "title": "Partner",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "partnerID": {
      "type": "string",
      "examples": [
        "0001038645"
      ]
    },
    "partnerTyp": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "NATPERS",
        "PAAR",
        "SONST-JURIST"
      ],
      "examples": [
        "SONST-JURIST"
      ]
    },
    "name": {
      "oneOf": [
          "vorname": {
            "type": "string",
            "examples": [
              "Bernd"
            ]
          },
          "nachname": {
            "type": "string",
            "examples": [
              "Wernersen"
            ]
          },
        },
        {
          "vorname1": {
            "type": "string",
            "examples": [
              "Bernd"
            ]
          },
        },
        {
          "nameExtern": {
            "type": "string",
            "examples": [
              "Internationale Pinsel Manufaktur Gesellschaft mbH"
            ]
          },
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

**Description**

That means we can have three different types of partners which would also result in different classes in kotlin. We want to save them in our database (mongodb).

Later on we want to get them to another application via REST.

**Problem**

We now have the problem that we do not know how to determine which type we need to save in the database when we are getting the message from the event.

In other Projects we have something like

`message.getBody(messageClass)`

But how to get the correct message class with Information in this event ?

And Further more how we get the correct type from the database later on.

```
interface ContractRepository : MongoRepository<Partner, String> {
    override fun deleteAll()
}
```

Can the Partner be an abstract class and when how does spring data knows whats the correct implemntation to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `everit-org/json-schema` library has a feature called [ValidationListener](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema#validationlisteners---tracking-the-validation-process) that reports events during validation, including `"oneOf"` subschema matches, so it probably provides enough information for you to determine the message class.

More precisely, if you run the validation with a `ValidationListener` configured, you will receive a `#combinedSchemaMatch(CombinedSchemaMatchEvent)` event, and the event's `#getSchema()` will return the wrapping `"oneOf"`, and the `#getSubSchema()` will return the actually matched subschema (which will tell you the message class).

The library is written in java, so you can use it from kotlin.

*Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the library.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it.